# Distance from point to plane compuation giving incorrect result

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, algebra

I'm having trouble calculating the distance from a point to a plane when I start using real-world coordinates.  I can get an example to work with dummy coordinates, using numbers between -10 and 10.  As soon as I apply the problem to real-world UTM coordinates, I start getting strange answers.

```
#  Using dummy coordinates
p1 = np.array([1.15, 0.62, -1.01])
p2 = np.array([1.74, 0.86, -0.88])
p3 = np.array([0.91, 0.79, -1.84])
tp =  np.array([1.17, 0.94, -1.52])

u = p2 - p1
v = p3 - p1
# vector normal to plane
n = np.cross(u, v)
n /= np.linalg.norm(n)

p_ = tp - p0
dist_to_plane = np.dot(p_, n)
print(dist_to_plane)

#  Using real-world coordinates
p1 = np.array([503562, 2811504, 1771], dtype='float64')
p2 = np.array([504122, 2810766, 1820], dtype='float64')
p3 = np.array([504325, 2811311, 1042], dtype='float64')
tp = np.array([503618, 2811286, 1808], dtype='float64')

u = p2 - p1
v = p3 - p1
# vector normal to plane
n = np.cross(u, v)
n /= np.linalg.norm(n)

p_ = tp - p0
dist_to_plane = np.dot(p_, n)
print(dist_to_plane)
```

Using dummy coordinates, I get dist = 0.115 which I believe is correct based on visual inspection.

Using real-world coordinates, I get dist = 1820961.09 which is definitely not correct.  The distance should be around 100.

Comment: Where is `p0` in your `p_ = tp - p0` expressions coming from?

Comment: FYI, change to `p_ = tp - p1` gives the distance equal to `-59.12`. You should return the absolute value of the dot product.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `p0` is undefined (as mentioned by Craig Meier).

Second, you don't need it. See the picture [here](http://www.mathnotes.org/content/math/algebra/linear/vectors/images/distance/distance_point_plane_visual.gif). What you need is to subtract point P, i.e. `p_ = tp - p1` in your code.

Third, remember to take the absolute value of your result (as mentioned by Quang Hoang).